# Invalid Style Sheet Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I was working on a gui and I needed to change the backgroung color of the QMainWindow, I opened 'styleSheet' parameter and clicked 'Add Color' button, chose the color but it is saying 'Invalid Style Sheet'. 'Help' button gives pretty weird path.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many properties of QSS are of the color type such as text color, border color, etc. so when placing `rgb(x, y, z)` you do not identify to which property you are setting that color. If you want to set the background color then you must use the background-color property:

```css
background-color: rgb(238, 6, 6)
```

I recommend you read:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html